# Thread-safety of sub-word-size flags

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

Consider the following scenario:

1. There exists a globally accessible variable `F`.
2. Thread `A` repeatedly assigns a random value to `F` (without any regard to the previous value of `F`).
3. Thread `B` does the same thing as thread `A` (independent of `A`).
4. Thread `C` repeatedly reads the value of `F` (and say, prints it).

This is in C++ (Visual C++) on Windows on x64 architecture, multi-processor. `F` is of type `bool` and marked `volatile`, and none of the accesses are protected by any locks.

Question: **Is there anything thread-unsafe about this scenario?**

Assuming that the logical behavior of the code is valid, is there anything unsafe about the fact that multiple threads are reading and writing the values to the same location at the same time?

What guarantees can be made (across architectures, OSes, compilers) about the atomicity of reading from and writing to variables that are <= word-size on the platform? (I am assuming word-size is important...)

On a related note, what is an acceptible way of communicating between threads the state of completion of some operation (none of the threads are waiting for the operation to complete, they may just be interested in querying the state from time to time)?

Comment: For the purposes of this question, you can assume there are no critical resources or anything of the like to be protected. The problem is merely one of signaling between threads the state of completion of certain operations, without any waiting being involved. Simple example would be one thread signaling another thread that it is now okay to stop doing what it is doing and exit.

Comment: It should be noted that `bool` will often be compiled as the native word or int size, so either 32bits or 64bits. That is, there's a good chance it won't be sub-word size.

Comment: So, you just want to cancel a thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your thread-safety requirements. You'll always get a consistent value (that is, it is impossible that you get half the value of thread A's write and the other half from thread B), but there is **no guarantee** that the value you'll read is, in fact, the latest one that was logically written.

The problem here is the CPU cache that may or may not get flushed. When a thread writes to the memory, the value first goes to the cache, and eventually it gets written to memory. In the while, if other cores attempt to read the object from memory, they'll get the old value.

Comment: In Visual C++ "volatile" gives you Acquire/Release semantics for reads/writes. Wouldn't that solve the problem you describe in my specific case? But yes, I agree you have made a valid point.

Comment: @TripShock I'm not sure the MSDN claim applies to x64. Also, I've seen others argue on this very site that that statement is not entirely true, even for x86. If this variable is governing concurrency of sections that are critical I'd say you should use a `CriticalSection` or a `Mutex` (if the concurrency needs to be interprocess)

Comment: @TripShock, yes, I would believe Microsoft's extension to `volatile` addresses the issue (though I can't back these claims myself, and Praetorian seems to argue the contrary). If MSVC++ supports C++11's atomic types, though, I'd go for them, since they were designed for this kind of situation.

Comment: You are correct that in TripShock's simplified scenario there is no guarantee as to what value he receives (from any thread, current or old). I wonder if the scenario is oversimplified however. Since the moment you start reading multiple variables written from one thread the CPUs do certainly have some ordering guarantees (usually that data is flushed in the order it is written).

Comment: @Praetorian: TripShock is right, also for x64. VC++ `volatile` _will_ give you Acquire/Release semantics. You might be confused because Acquire/Release by itself will not magically fix all threading isses. (The same applies to C++11 atomics)

Comment: "_the latest_" With MT programming, there is no such thing as "latest" anything.

Comment: @TripShock "_In Visual C++ "volatile" gives you Acquire/Release semantics for reads/writes._" I am not sure what `volatile` does, because the MS doc, is, as usual, less than clear (shall we say: deficient).

Answer (score 2):

Under x86, any read or write to a type correctly aligned for its size is considered to be atomic (so for a `bool` it need only be a 1 byte alignment boundery), but its recommended to use explict atomic ops for portability and the memory barriers they provide. An excerpt from the Intel System Programming Guide, Vol 3A, Section 8. May 2011 (there is another one as well, can't find it atm).

> The Intel486 processor (and newer processors since) guarantees that the following
>   basic memory operations will always be carried out atomically:
>
> • Reading or writing a byte
>
> • Reading or writing a word aligned on a 16-bit boundary
>
> • Reading or writing a doubleword aligned on a 32-bit boundary
>
> The Pentium processor (and newer processors since) guarantees that the following
>   additional memory operations will always be carried out atomically:
>
> • Reading or writing a quadword aligned on a 64-bit boundary
>
> • 16-bit accesses to uncached memory locations that fit within a 32-bit data bus
>
> The P6 family processors (and newer processors since) guarantee that the following
>   additional memory operation will always be carried out atomically:
>
> • Unaligned 16-, 32-, and 64-bit accesses to cached memory that fit within a cache
>   line

Microsoft also has [a few examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a04hfd%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) of using `volatitle bool`'s for signaling thread exits, however, if you want to signal threads that are waiting, its best to use kernel constructs, on windows this would be a event (see `CreateEventA/W`), this will prevent the wait from burning cpu cycles when the variable hasn't been set yet.

### Update:

For threads that will have almost zero wait time, its a good idea to implement a user level lock, with optional backoff if its a high contention enviroment, intel has a good article on that [here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/implementing-scalable-atomic-locks-for-multi-core-intel-em64t-and-ia32-architectures/), alternatively you can use WinAPI's CriticalSections (these are semi-kernel level).

Comment: Like I mentioned in the last part of my question, there is no waiting involved. If there were waiting, yes, using events or some other kernel object would be a good idea.

Comment: @TripShock: update the question for no waiting events, as for ARM, I wouldn't have a clue, you'd need to consult their architecture manuals